# How to save a converted pdf through Graph API in a folder within sharepoint

Tags: excel, pdf, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I have an excel template within a private sharepoint site. Im going to copy the excel document to a folder called Folder 2 using Microsoft Graph API Copy Item. The copied excel document (which is .xlsx) will be edited by using Graph Creat workbook session, within an active session I will set all the values with  Update Worksheet API. Once finished I want to turn the edited .xlsx file into a .pdf file. I know it can be done with this endpoint described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

> GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content?format={format}

the output which Microsoft describes is something like this:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Location:
> https://b0mpua-by3301.files.1drv.com/y23vmagahszhxzlcvhasdhasghasodfi

So how do I get this converted PDF file into Folder 2 or ANY folder within my private sharepoint site?

Is the expected behaviour to download this file into a binary variable and then use Graph Upload Item?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same challenge with a Word document stored in our Graph that I also wanted to have in pdf format in the same folder.

You use a Graph call on the document to convert it to pdf.  The call is pretty simple and documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). It returns a full URL to the newly created pdf.

The wrinkle for me was the that the URL to the newly created pdf is part of the Location header returned from the Graph call.  So you need to make sure that your curl response is set to include the headers not just the body.

Then, when you have the response with the headers included, you need to parse out only the URL to the new pdf from the headers.  The URL starts after "Location:" and ends with "PUBLISHED"

Once you have the URL to where the new pdf is located you can use that full URL as the doc path in another  Graph call to Upload the pdf to where you want your own Graph.

Note: It was indicated that the URL for the new pdf is only good for a few minutes or so.